# call vi from within vim (useful for svn commit)

Tags: linux, vim

I am using RedHat EL 5. I use gvim 7.1 compiled using GTK. What I want is to be able to do an svn commit (which uses vi/vim) from within gvim. Currently the only problem is that I get output which is garbled.
For example, calling :!vi produces this from within gvim:

```
[7;1H~
                                     [8;1H~
                                           [9;1H~
                                                 [10;1H~
                                                        [11;1H~
                                                               [12;1H~
                                                                      [13;1H~
                                                                             [14;1H~
                                                                                    [15;1H~
                                                                                           [16;1H~
                                                                                                  [
17;1H~
     [18;1H~
            [19;1H~
                   [20;1H~
                          [21;1H~
                                 [22;1H~
                                        [23;1H~
                                               [24;1H~
                                                      [25;1H~
                                                             [26;1H~
                                                                    [27;1H~
                                                                           [28;1H~
                                                                                  [29;1H~
                                                                                         [30;1H~
                                                                                                [31
;1H~
   [32;1H~
          [33;1H~
                 [34;1H~
                        [35;1H~
                               [36;1H~
                                      [37;1H~
                                             [38;1H~
                                                    [39;1H~
                                                           [15;42HVIM - Vi IMproved[17;43Hversion
7.0.237[18;39Hby Bram Moolenaar et al.[19;29HVim is open source and freely distributable[21;36HHe
lp poor children in Uganda![22;28Htype  :help iccf<Enter>       for information [24;28Htype  :q<En
ter>               to exit         [25;28Htype  :help<Enter>  or  <F1>  for on-line help[26;28Htyp
e  :help version7<Enter>   for version info[1;1H
```

How do I configure vi/vim/gvim to solve this problem and thereby enable my svn commits to look proper when called from gvim.

Thank you,
Nachum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `vi` as the command, use `gvim -f` instead.

The problem is that `vi` (or `vim` in a console) requires a terminal that can do stuff like move the cursor around, etc. gvim's pty is a very basic ASCII-only terminal.

Plain old `vim` doesn't have this issue because it just pipes the subporcess directly to your terminal, hence all of the escape sequences still work.

You can use `gvim -f` instead, so that a new gvim window will pop up for your commit message. (the `-f` prevents backgrounding) This isn't exactly what you asked for (since you get a new window) but it's the closest you can get to what you asked for without adding full terminal support to vim.

Answer (score 2):

I use [VCSCommand](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=90), a nice VCS wrapper that works with SVN, GIT and others. `:VCSCommit` or `,cc` opens a new window under the current one, lets you type your message and does the actual commit on write. Sure that's one more plugin in your setup but the conveniance may be worth it. It is for me.